# Do I need a transcript to re-enter the US along with my F1 visa and I-20 form?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, f1-visas

I'm a French PhD student in a US University. I'm going abroad for 3 weeks. Do I need a transcript to re-enter the US along with my F1 visa and I-20 form? If so does the transcript have to be official?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need a transcript. Here is the list of the requirements from the [US Immigration and Customs Enforcement website](http://www.ice.gov/sevis/travel/faq_f2.htm#_Toc81222002):

> 1. A Form I-20, endorsed for travel and signed by your DSO
> 2. You have been out of the United States for less than five months
> 3. A current passport valid for at least six months after the date of your reentry or, if you are from one of the countries listed below, a
>      passport that is current through the date of entry
> 4. A valid, current visa or you traveled to contiguous country or adjacent island for less than thirty days
> 5. Financial information showing proof of necessary funds to cover tuition and living expenses
>
> If you are from a visa exempt country, you do not need a visa to reenter the United States from the western hemisphere, but make sure that you present your I-20 to be admitted as an F-1 student and not a visitor.